# Android Google Cast Notification disable

Tags: android, casting

I integrated Google cast to my Android app. All my content is playing via service with notification. When I play media using Google cast it add own notification. Is it possible to disable default google cast notification and use only own notification?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is great portal, you ask some question, than you answer own qustion by yourself :)

To disable cast notification needed just to pass null while for setNotificationOptions() in class CastOptionsProvider.

Complete answer:

```
public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {

    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {

        CastMediaOptions mediaOptions = new CastMediaOptions.Builder().setNotificationOptions(null).build();
        return new CastOptions.Builder().setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id)).setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions).build();
    }

    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: not in a million years would I have guessed such an important thing is hidden in this class. Awesome finding!