# Google cast v3 notification and foreground service notification

Tags: android, google-cast

I am using ExoPlayer in foreground service together with MediaStyle notification and MediaSessionToken to control playback. I also want to be able to Cast the content to Google Cast receiver. This could be the normal use case for every music player.

The cast is creating its own notification so I have 2 notifications to control the same playback which is bad UX.

I have found this SO question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754783/android-google-cast-notification-disable) to disable the default cast notification by setting `.setNotificationOptions(null)`. The problem is that the system creates another notification "A device on your Wi-Fi is casting" as seen on the screenshot. This is the notification that is shown on every device in the same network.

My question is: Is it possible to share the same notification for foreground service and cast service?

Or at least tell the system that this is the device that is actually sending the cast, so it won't show the silent system notification "A device on your Wi-Fi is casting" on that particular device?

[image: doubled notification screen shot]

Thank you.